# How to set a foreign key to a sequenced id

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, sequence

I have the following table definition for `journal`

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."journal" (
"id" "public"."inc_journal" NOT NULL,
"short_desc" varchar(20),
"description" varchar(1000),
"default_gl_account_id" int8,
"company_id" int2,
"creator_user_id" int4,
"created_date" timestamp(6),
"type" "public"."journal_type",
CONSTRAINT "journal_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE)
;
```

The def for inc_journal is a sequence like so:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "public"."inc_journal"
 INCREMENT 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 4294967295
 START 1
 CACHE 1;
```

And I wish to set a foreign key to it like so:

```
ALTER TABLE "public"."entry"
ADD FOREIGN KEY ("journal_id") REFERENCES "public"."journal" ("id");
```

However when I do this I get an error:

> [Err] ERROR:  foreign key constraint "entry_journal_id_fkey" cannot be implemented
>   DETAIL:  Key columns "journal_id" and "id" are of incompatible types: integer and inc_journal.

How do I get rid of this error?
Do I need to set `journal_id` to type `inc_journal`? I'd like to still insert `null` into the field, so this does not seem the right option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using field type `serial` for you PKey, or

```
id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('inc_journal')
```

This will create/use a sequence for your PKey. You can then FKey any integer fields you want. See also http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL .

Comment: +1 That makes a lot of sense, coming from MySQL so I'm up against a bit of a learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sequerize ORM and get the error try the following.

I made a mistake where `Foreign key field` of a `product` table had different type as `Primary key field` of a `user` table. When I match the type, it works!

> Example

```js
// user 
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,     // Foreign key type should match with PK
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
   }

// product
    userId: {
      type: Sequelize.UUID,  // FK type should be the same as PK type
      allowNull: false,
      references: {
      model: 'Users',
      key: 'id',
    },
```